# Dealing with `show` in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a function `ip`, which I can not change:

```
ip = show a ++ show b ++ show c ++ show d
```

and I have to define `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` so that:

```
GHCi> ip
"127.224.120.12"
```

holds. How do I do that?

Comment: There are several ways to do that. What trouble are you having?

Comment: Conceptual. If I define, say, `a = "127"`, `show` adds all the quotes and escape sequences, and the concatenation result is wrong. If I make `a = 127.`, Haskell treats the dot as a function. And so on.

Comment: So what other type could you use?

Comment: I don't see it as a question of types, I see it as a way `show` turns arguments into `String`s. Maybe that's my problem.

Comment: This sounds more like a puzzle than a programming problem. Have you tried http://codegolf.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Not yet. Can someone migrate it there?

Comment: @dfeuer It was [not a good fit for ppcg](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/60466/4256).

Comment: @hexafraction, that is because it's not a good fit anywhere.

Comment: @dfeuer Then a vote to close would be more appropriate than a migration suggestion. However, although I'm not familiar with Haskell, the fact that a good answer could be given that was rated well by both asker and community leads me to believe that it was fine here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different ways you can do this. In any case, the default `Show` instances are probably unsuitable to you, this is the core of the problem: you will want to define your own type, with a custom `Show` instance. The common way to redefine types with custom instances (or hiding instances) is using `newtype`.

We can use a different `Show` instance with a `String`-like type, so that there is no escaping or addition of `"`:

```
newtype MyStr = MyStr String

instance Show MyStr where
  show (MyStr s) = s

ip a b c d = show a ++ show b ++ show c ++ show d

a = MyStr "127."
b = MyStr "224."
c = MyStr "120."
d = MyStr "12"

main = print $ ip a b c d
```

Another possibility would be to define an alternative for the `Int` type where a `.` is appended when using `show`. We then use this type for the first three arguments of `ip` and use a regular `Int` for the last argument (`a`, `b`, `c` and `d` can have different types).

```
newtype MyInt = MyInt Int

instance Show MyInt where
  show (MyInt s) = show s ++ "."

ip a b c d = show a ++ show b ++ show c ++ show d

a = MyInt 127
b = MyInt 224
c = MyInt 120
d = 12

main = print $ ip a b c d
```

Note that in both cases the solution is a bit of a hack, but this is because of the nature of the problem. Normally you would want instances of `Show` to be technical rather than "stylistic" in nature: you want to show all information on a value, preferably in a way that can be read back with `read` (by defining a corresponding `Read` instance). For styling output a pretty printer is more suitable.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not the solution that was expected, but it's clever and it works, so thanks.

Comment: @Chiffa: I would be interested in hearing about the expected solution if it's very different. I can't really think of another way than using a custom `Show` instance.

Comment: I'll definitely post it once I get it.

Comment: @Chiffa: I suggest you accept chi's answer instead, it's better.

Answer (score 10):

With floating point numbers:

```
> let ip a b c d = show a ++ show b ++ show c ++ show d
> ip 127.2 24.12 0.1 2
"127.224.120.12"
```

Comment: This is exactly the sort of answer I had in mind when I recommended CodeGolf instead of this site. Sadly, others saw it differently.

Comment: Could you go to codegolf, find my question there and copypaste this answer? I'd say that's exactly it.

Comment: @Chiffa The question on codegolf has been put on hold, so no answers can be posted.

Comment: @dfeuer I guess that the "puzzle" aspect of this question is only understandable by Haskellers, since it depends on how `show` is defined. Non-haskellers would probably guess that `show=id` on `String`, since e.g. `someString.toString()` is the same as `someString` in some OOP languages. If that were the case, there would be no challenge at all to solve this. I'm not surprised if CodeGolfers simply thought that this was a regular general programming question.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ip` function will be different depending on what you want to use for `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`:

If you choose Strings:

```
ip1 :: String -> String -> String -> String -> String
ip1 a b c d = a ++ "." ++ b ++ "." ++ c ++ "." ++ d
```

and if you choose Ints:

```
ip2 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> String
ip2 a b c d = show a ++ "." ++ show b ++ "." ++ show c ++ "." ++ show d
```

**Update**

Maybe these examples of creating new types and Show instances for them
will help:

```
data Foo = F String

instance Show Foo where
    show (F string) = "a string of length " ++ show (length string)

data Bar = B Double

instance Show Bar where
    show (B adouble) = if adouble > 0 then "(positive)" else "(not positive)"

a = F "abc"
b = B 14.0
```

Then:

```
show a ++ show b
```

results in:

```
"a string of length 3(positive)"
```

Comment: I don't have control over `show`, I can only provide the right arguments. Otherwise your solutions are great, and I've already thought of those.

Comment: You know what the types of a,b,c,d are. You can't define `ip` where sometimes `a` is an Int and sometimes it is a String. Show us more of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to choose `a`, `b` and so on in such a way that `show` doesn't add any extra symbols to them.